# How to create an unkown number of SQLite tables in Android based on user input

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create tables based on new categories that are created in my Android app. I have a Table that keeps track of the category that the user entered and the perspective table name for that category, but I cannot figure out how to actually create new tables based on the perspective table names. I am new to SQLite and I am wondering if this is even possible

Comment: why create new tables for each Categories. Create a Category table that holds category name, id and a mapping table to which u hv to link the category too

Comment: `I am new to SQLite` It seems you are new to the concept of database, in general.

Comment: What is a mapping table @NidhinPrathap

Comment: Mapping table is ordinatory table tat links ur category table and the desired table .... Lets say Table A  is your category table, Table B is the User Posts Table. Now you want the user to save the Post as a new Category... so 1st a record is made in Table A, the new Categories ID is taken and linked with Users post in Table C like Category id->PostId..... Basically mapping table is a relation table that specifies the relation between 2 or more tables

Comment: https://community.qlik.com/thread/48576

Comment: Note: Mapping or (better) "Look-Up" Tables are only needed in a `many-to-many` relation.

Comment: @internetRando, Is the number of categories known upfront or new categories may be added when your app is running? Is the category information structurally exactly similar or each category may have its own set of different attributes ('columns')?

Comment: @DamodarPeriwal new categories may be added that have the same columns, would it be better to just make one table that has a category column?

Comment: If all categories are similar in structure, that is each one has the same attributes (i.e., id, name, description, etc.), you may just create a database table (say Category) with corresponding columns (i.e., id, name, description, etc.) and keep adding new category rows to this table as and when needed by your app. It is not clear from your question if you need to store additional information (records) per category. If that is the case, you should create another table which would have multiple records with the same category id (foreign key) linking these records to the corresponding category.

Comment: Continuing the previous response, that is a situation of one-to-many relationship. However, if that additional information may belong (relate) to multiple categories then you have a situation of many-to-many relationship as mentioned in prior posts by others. That is typically handled with a join table (a.k.a. mapping table or link table), a third table that links the records of the first two tables with the values of their primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

why create new tables for each Categories. Create a Category table that holds category name, id and a **mapping table** to which u hv to link the category too

**Mapping table** is ordinatory table tat links ur category table and the desired table .... Lets say Table A is your category table, Table B is the User Posts Table. Now you want the user to save the Post as a new Category... so 1st a record is made in Table A, the new Categories ID is taken and linked with Users post in Table C like Category id->PostId..... Basically mapping table is a relation table that specifies the relation between 2 or more tables

**Refer this for Mapping Table**

community.qlik.com/thread/48576

Comment: Note: Mapping or (better) "Look-Up" Tables are only needed in a many-to-many relation.